# How is fall damage calculated in Fortnite Battle Royale?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

Does fall damage only affect your health, and not shield?

Approximately how far do I have to fall to die?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, yes, the fall damage just affects your health, not the shield.
Second, you can fall off three floors until you take damage. If you fall off six floors, you die.

Comment: Note that fall damage does not apply when you have grappled a target with the [Grappler](https://fortnite.gamepedia.com/Grappler) and are pulling toward it. Go figure, you will take NO damage if you grapple to the ground and pull yourself *toward* it even faster... however, if you simply fall that same distance you may die. (I understand the devs choosing fun-factor over realism here, but I still think the Grappler gives too big of an advantage. If you're going to use it, you should understand that the normal physics of fall damage do not apply.)